# How to avoid "Redefinition" and "Duplicate Protocol" definition errors in Bridging Header

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to use a objc library and a objc class in a swift class. So I place the following in the Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import <FooLibrary/FooLibrary.h>
#import "FooClass.h"
```

The problem is that the FooClass.h has

```
#import "FooLibrary.h".
```

So when I compile I get hundreds of errors like:"Redefinition of enumerator" and "Property has previous definition" and "Duplicate protocol definition" and "Typedef redefinition"

How do I avoid this? It seems like this is just a stupid mental block I am having but I can't get past it so here I am asking.

PartiallyFinite suggested I watch for `#include`

I did a project wide search and I and not using it at all. There are a few in the library. I chose one of the errors. The file the decoration is in is never included in any file with `#include`

Comment: This should be avoided automatically, as `#import` makes sure that each file is only imported once. Are you sure you aren't accidentally using `#include` somewhere instead? (`#include` doesn't include checks to ensure files are only imported once)

Comment: @PartiallyFinite see my edit. Thanks for the comment. I had not checked for that, but it still doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like something is causing the preprocessor to believe that the `FooLibrary.h` header imported indirectly by the second `#import` is somehow not the same file as the one you include just above it. My best guess as to *what* is that your first, framework-style import is referencing header files that are copied to a build location during build, while your second, direct file import is referencing the header file as it is in your project directory, meaning that the preprocessor sees them as two completely separate files, resulting in it being imported twice.

Proposed ways to fix:

1. If you can include `FooClass.h` using the framework-style import syntax (like `#import <FooLibrary/FooClass.h>`), that will *probably* fix the problem.
2. If you're absolutely sure that `FooClass.h` will *always* include `FooLibrary.h`, you can probably just omit the first import entirely, as everything will get imported indirectly via the second one.
3. Otherwise, you can try some nice, old-fashioned include guards (assuming you have write access to the library headers):

   ```
   // FooLibrary.h

   #pragma once // Maybe even throw in one of these for good measure;
                // since we're dealing with an obscure-sounding bug,
                // may as well try to fix it in all of the possible ways

   #ifndef FOOLIBRARY_IMPORTED
   #define FOOLIBRARY_IMPORTED
   ... // actual file contents
   #endif
   ```

   This will define a preprocessor macro the first time the file is imported, so the second time the preprocessor tries to import the file, the already defined macro will prevent the contents from being imported a second time. I fail to understand why the `#import` isn't doing this in your case, as that's literally its only purpose and advantage over `#include`, but if this fixes it, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: 1. The class had `#import "FooLibrary.h` I changed it to `#import <FooLibrary/FooLibrary.h>` and this fixed it. (Is that what you wanted to say with #1? That isn't what I understood from it but that is what made me try what did work.)

Comment: 2. Worked with a few caveats. I'll just go thru a few scenarios. 

Scenario 1 worked: Remove `#import <FooLibrary/FooLibrary.h>` from the bridging-header.

Scenario 2 failed: Remove `#import <FooLibrary/FooLibrary.h>` from the bridging-header. FooClass.h has `#import <FooLibrary/FooLibrary.h> from the bridging-header` AnotherFooClass.h has `#import "FooLibrary.h` - this produces the same problem. 

I did not try 3.

Comment: @LucasGoossen that's what I was saying with #1. Your header files are being copied somewhere during build, and it was importing the copied one as well as the original one, without realising that they were the same.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by cocoapods - try upgrading or downgrading to a different version and re-running `pod install`

Comment: I'm using cocoapods and 1. in the suggestion above worked for me

Answer (score 2):

For me it was happening when I upgraded Xcode. All I did was to Clean Build folder and run again and it worked!